# Unity multiplayer: Different devices show different physics even without interaction

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, multiplayer

i'm developing a multiplayer game using sockets where players run  with constant speed. Players can only jump. Their movement has constant speed applied like below in FixedUpdate. (tried also update) On client, i start enemies with 300ms latency to get their jump info before they get to the position of jump.

//run

```
    body.velocity = new Vector2(runSpeed, body.velocity.y);
```

//jump

```
        body.velocity = new Vector2(body.velocity.x, jumpForce);
```

I have 2 ideas to syncronize their jump.

1) When player jump,i emit exact position of jump x,y to other clients. In the other player, when i get info about an enemies jump, i dont do anything about it while enemy is still behind its jump position. When it passes or on the point of jump i suddenly move player to jump position in 0.3ms ( to have exact physics ) and apply jump on enemy.

2)  I count everytime velocity applied to player and each enemies. When jump, i emit that count and on the side of other player, when jumped enemy has the same count as its jump, i apply jump.

Those are my ideas however, even when running  the physics are different. Its not about jump, i have 2 computers and i sync the code and start the game in both computers and i never do any user action. I just print transform.position.x and transform.position.y to the screen. However they are different, i think this is the cause of my syncronizing problem. I cant have perfectly same physics on different computers but the same source code.. Please help.

In both pictures which represents game in different computers, i never touched a button

[image: COMPUTER 1]

[image: COMPUTER 2]

Comment: is one player the moon sprite, and the other player the beach ball?

Comment: @ErikOverflow Yes, their body and everything is the same.  But its not related,  since  printings belongs to player on both computers. I'm comparing  player to player which are completely identical.

Answer (score 3):

Unity doesn't have deterministic physics. Simulating the same exact situation across 2 different devices will not return the same exact result due to tiny inconsistencies between the fixed time interval.

You can simulate every player, but you can not rely on both players being in the exact same position on each machine. There are a few ways to handle this, but the ultimate result will be that all machines will need to occasionally synchronize.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i achieve this? How i should share jump event? Its not problem on straight walking how ever when you jump multiple times like in stairs they cant be the same.. Do you know how?  Also, you can tell me some keywords to search too.. @ErikOverflow

Comment: @FeritÖzcan The most common solution is to have a "host" server that all other clients connect to. This can be done peer-to-peer. Unity doesn't have a well-defined networking layer at the moment, but you can find many examples and packages out there that can help you achieve this via search engine.

Comment: Actually, i use nodejs as my game server.. really is it s must to use photon or any other game server to achieve this syncronization? I m very excited about writing my own server:(

Comment: You can use your nodejs server, but you'll likely need to identify one of your players as the trusted client that the server treats as "host". All players can perform physics locally, but the "host" would send their physics calculations to the server alongside their input. If the other player's logic differs, then they can synchronize to that value. @FeritÖzcan

Comment: @FeritÖzcan Netcode is a very complex area. Do some research on p2p netcode. That might help you.

Comment: I read about those authority server stuff all the week but i think that doesnt adress my problem.  Even if  there is no interaction, physics are different on two client. How i should share jump event and process it on other client?

Comment: Can i email you please?  I will be very glad and wont bother you please...  Feritzcan93 @ gmail.com

Comment: Physics will always be very slightly different on your 2 clients @FeritÖzcan You cannot change this. You can either: 1. move the physics calculation to a centralized server. or 2. treat one of your clients as the "master" and make the other client "course correct" to match it.

Comment: Please contact me from email i need ur 15 min please.